# Is there a hidden meaning of "swinging the club"?

Tags: idioms, translation

Does "swinging the club" have another meaning outside the world of golf ?

Comment: I do not think so. However, the phrase is used in a metaphorical sense in the title here. "Swinging the club: relations between the United States and the British Commonwealth in the economic transition from war to peace," 1943-1948 Author Nicholas Wise Norman Publisher University of London, 1994. PS: I haven't read the book, so I would not know much about the metaphor in it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it does, and context is everything.

*The golfer was swinging the club to warm up his shoulder.*

*When it comes to swinging the club, no one rocks like Elvis.*

*The cave man confronted the tiger, swinging the club wildly.*

*The new manager was fired after swinging the club from fame to notoriety and disrepute.*

*The card player grinned, swinging the club under his opponents nose before claiming the trick.*

*It was like a baby's arm, and when he started swinging the club (as they called it) it intimidated everyone on the set.*

*He manhandled him onto the horse, jamming the boy's good foot into a stirrup and swinging the club foot over the saddle.*

Comment: Does "No band has ever swung the club as hard as Duke Ellington's" work too?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the "baby's arm" example.

Comment: @Martha: You don't want to understand. You're in happy, naïve baby mode; just enjoy it while you can!

Comment: In the Royal Navy, **Club Swinger** is slang for [Physical Trainer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Training_Instructor).

Comment: @EdGuiness: The OP refers to *outside the world of golf* (and bridge, if you please!). Moreover, it is about the whole phrase used metaphorically, not the individual words used literally.

Comment: @Kris So you say.